# Stata year display different than stored format

Tags: panel, stata

I am working with Stata and have a panel dataset with years ranging from 1990 to 2015. When browsing the data, the years are displayed as 1990, 1991 and so on. However, for instance, when trying to drop a year, it only works the following way

```
drop if year==11
```

which results in dropping the year 2000. When plotting data, the ticks are also displayed as 1,2,3,4...,25, 26,  instead of the actual years.

How can I convert back years into their actual values?

Comment: Note https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve as giving the standard for questions. My answer required some guesses. If it's not the correct answer, you'll need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you or someone else read in the data with `year` as a string variable and then used `encode` to generate a numeric variable. That's quite the wrong approach, as you have found out: you do **not** want the string to be mapped to integers 1 up. You need `destring` for that situation. Now that you have done this, you need `decode` and then `destring` or (if the original variable is still present in the dataset) `destring`.

Note that you should check your data carefully. Why was year imported in this way in the first place? Often this happens when data come from a spreadsheet and people don't check carefully enough for metadata (e.g. header information).

```
clear
input str4 original 
"1990"
"1991"
"1992"
end 
encode original, gen(year) 

* solution 1 
decode year, gen(year2) 
destring year2, replace 

* solution 2 (better) 
destring original, replace 

list 

     +-------------------------+
     | original   year   year2 |
     |-------------------------|
  1. |     1990   1990    1990 |
  2. |     1991   1991    1991 |
  3. |     1992   1992    1992 |
     +-------------------------+
```

Also, in Stata, "format" is nothing to do with what is stored, but with what is displayed. See `help format`. It is, naturally, an overloaded term in computing.

Comment: The data was imported from an Excel sheet, with all a `General` cell format, not sure exactly why years were imported as strings, and no relevant info available in the metadata, either.  However, indeed, I used the encode command to transform the variable into numeric, but now that`s fixed, thanks Nick for the help!

Comment: That's not enough detail to work out what happened on the `import`. Did you use `import excel` or `import delimited` or copy and pasteor what? What did you do about any metadata, e.g. column headers? Note the `firstrow` option of `import excel`. Any way, now you know that `encode` is a bad idea for string variables with numeric content to be taken literally.